# Smallest_multiple function in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab

Hi I am having problems with the following function in Matlab. Can some please help?
2520 is the smallest number that can be divided by each of the numbers from 1 to 10 without any remainder. Write a function called smallest_multiple that returns a uint64, the smallest positive number that is evenly divisible by all of the numbers from 1 to n where n is a positive integer scalar and is the only input argument of the function. If the result would be greater than what can be represented as a uint64, the function returns 0. (Inspired by Project Euler.)

Below is the code I wrote for the function but it gives error 
    Feedback: Your function made an error for argument(s) 2

```
Your solution is _not_ correct.
```

Help please...

```
function [answer]=smallest_multiple(n)
limit = 1e10;

N = 20;

for i = N:N:limit

    for j = N:-1:1

    if mod(i,j) ~= 0

        break

    end

end

if j == 1

    answer = i;

    break

    end

end

fprintf('The smallest evenly divisible number is %.0d\n',answer)
```

Comment: Possibly because you're setting `N = 20;` (plus having the incorrect argument as @fcdimitr mentioned).

Comment: Hey thank you for your kind help, I removed the value of N and ran it again but still the error persists....Any help please.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you run your code?

Comment: Hi, looking at the question it states that the function should have only 1 input. Now in the next line we have limit as limit of N, so we need to rectify that for the code to run and infact replace N in the entire code. Could you help me with that. I think fixing that issue might make it run fine

Comment: You didn't answer my question.

Comment: Problem 4 (smallest_multiple):
    Feedback: Your program made an error for argument(s) 2

    Your solution is _not_ correct.

Comment: That's what you get when you run your function in MATLAB? That doesn't look like any MATLAB error message I've ever seen.

Comment: I have an auto grader to test the correctness of my code and it tests the code using random inputs

Comment: Seriously? How do you expect to debug your code if you don't actually run it in an environment where you can see what it's doing?

Comment: The auto grader runs the function in MATLAB using different input arguments and tells us on which input arguments its giving error.

Comment: Calling this function in  matlab from the command window gives the error

Comment: Undefined function or variable "answer".

Error in smallest_multiple (line 13)
fprintf('The smallest evenly divisible number is %.0d\n',answer)

Comment: The code runs successfully on my end. Try smallest_multiple(10,10e10) for my answer. If you need, put limit as an inside variable, so that you only have 1 argument.

Comment: @ishika What value did you pass to your function to produce this error? Have you stepped through your program to see why that input would produce this particular error? Did you try the values that your auto grader said were giving incorrect results? What was the output for those?

Comment: Hi I just need a little help before I can answer your question. How can I rewrite the above code without the limit. How can I define i without the limit, or if I have to define limit as an inside variable what will be its value. Sorry for too many questions, I am just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function looks correct. However the argument you pass is a lowercase `n` instead of an uppercase `N`, which you use during your code.

So the correct function (with limit as argument) is

```
function [answer]=smallest_multiple(N,limit)

for i = N:N:limit

    for j = N:-1:1

        if mod(i,j) ~= 0
            break
        end

    end

    if j == 1
        answer = i;
        break
    end

end

fprintf('The smallest evenly divisible number is %.0d\n',answer)
```

Comment: Hi..Thank you so much for your help! But the function still gives the same error. Any other way to deal with it..Thanks in advance, its kinda urgent

Comment: Also the question states that N or n should be the only input argument, so may b the limit needs to replaced with something else for i to make it run...Thanks